# Dropdown navigation menu <li> centering issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, centering, navigationbar

I've spent hours going through a lot of code online trying to center this dropdown menu, but no luck. I feel like I've changed everything in my code twice and I'm at the end of this particular rope.

As you can see, there's space between the right side of the dropdown list and the unordered list that contains it.

I also can't get any transitions to work with the dropdown, so if you feel like sharing some information about that as well it would be appreciated.

Here's the trouble-maker.

```html
<li class="nav"><a href="#" id="about">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <ul id="portfolio_menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="paintings">PAINTINGS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="drawings">DRAWINGS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cartoons">CARTOONS</a></li>
    </ul>
</li><!--portfolio-->
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x514tmrx/)

Comment: How direct li without ul ?

Comment: There's a gap because you're explicitly setting a 4px `margin-right` on the `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is margin right in your list because you have it in your css. Remove the `margin-right:4px;`. As I can see the text was center. Please explain it more.

```
ul#navbar_ul li{  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
 margin-right: 4px; /*REMOVE THIS*/
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out. That's a pretty large mistake to miss. Thanks for the perfect answer.

Answer (score -1):

In your code the following code will target all the li elemnts. If you want to apply only first level of child then use `>`. This will resolve your space issue.

```
ul#navbar_ul li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Change it to like below.

```
ul#navbar_ul > li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/x514tmrx/1/)